# Goodness of Fit test with PDF, not data

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, goodness-of-fit

I have a  sample probability distribution and want to know how well a Gaussian would fit to it. However, I just have a probability distribution to test, and not an actual data sample. (Nor do I want to create one, as that would be fairly computational expensive if you have several hundred of these.)

How would I go about testing how well a Gaussian can fit to it? I could do a simple rms error, but is there any standard way in addressing this?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:
Hello, thanks for the comments. To clarify, the way I get this distribution is by running a simulation with a set of parameters 1000 times, and thus getting  1000 points, from which we can make a weibull distribution. This gives a shape and scale parameter. However, Its not possible  to run a simulation for every set of parameters in our set 1000 times. So I'm trying to see if we can just run a simulation once for a given set of parameters, and then add  error bounds on that value. The way I'm trying to figure out bounds is by creating a series of Weibull fits(with the same shape and scale parameter determined by the 1000 points) centered around an arbitrarily sample value (lets call it t), normalized by the probability of actually sampling that value.  So you get something similar to the graph below. [image]

The left figure just shows a series of Weibull distributions overlapped with each other centered around a discrete set of about 500 values of t, and the left graph is a summation of all those distributions, which ends up being a different distribution. So I have data used to generate the distribution on the left, but not for the right. The right distribution is what I'm interested in fitting a Gaussian for.

Comment: At the outset you seem to say two contradictory things: you have a "sample probability distribution" but "not an actual data sample." Could you please explain, then, what a "sample probability distribution" might be and how you arrived at it?

Comment: If the OP means the empirical distribution then you could do a Kolmogorov - Smirnov test. But you would know the data from the jump point of the ECDF. But you wouldn't have a density function.

Comment: I agree with whuber. It is not clear what you mean by a sample probability distribution. Could it be kernel density estimate?  It is mysterious how you would get that without the data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've add clarification, let me know if that helps!

Comment: The distribution on the right is clearly skewed; why would you fit a Gaussian to that?

Comment: This one partiular example is a bit skewed, but not all are. Regardless, that does not answer my question.